# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field jdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, jdbc, dao

I am unsure of how to fix the error that I keep getting which is

```
An An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name ...
```

I'm sure I probably am missing a config file, or something in the properties file I have...

herer is my applicaiton.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp

spring.datasource.url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=AssetTracking
spring.datasource.username: user
spring.datasource.password: pass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

welcome.message: Hello Justin
```

and the relavent(?) bits of my DAO file

```
public class AssetDAO {

private String query;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List<Employee> getAllEmployeeRecords() {
        query = "select * from Employee";

        ArrayList<Employee> retval = new ArrayList<>();

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        List list = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from Employee");

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Iterator iterate = list.iterator();

        while(iterate.hasNext())
            retval.add((Employee) iterate.next());

        return retval;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: As per request the full stack trace (my bad for not including it the first time :/ )

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field jdbcTemplate in com.assetTracking.AssetDAO required a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'jdbcTemplate' not loaded because @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans


Action:

Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' in your configuration.

[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:506)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'assetDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jdbcTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject (AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:592)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject (InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues (AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject (AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:754)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization (AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh (EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at com.assetTracking.App.main (App.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:506)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1466)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1097)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject (AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:589)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject (InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues (AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject (AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:754)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization (AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh (EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at com.assetTracking.App.main (App.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:506)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.809 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-21T15:15:25+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 32M/260M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project AssetTrackingTest: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'assetDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jdbcTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)} -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Please show the complete stack trace!

Comment: You're using the `@Autowired` annotation, but have you instantiated that anywhere when your app starts up to be used?

Comment: Those were my initial thoughts, I'm not entirely sure where or which file I need to instantiate it in.